# How to accept merge request via web interface online in gitlabhq?

Tags: git, gitlab

I used gitlabhq 2.5, my team member checkout a local branch named `feature1` and add some feature, then push to remote origin `feature1` branch.

And he create a merge request in "Merge request" tab, but I can't merge his request. There is an alert message show " Checking for ability to automatically merge…"

What is the problem? Is there something I haven't setup right?

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer myself:

```
rake gitlab:app:enable_automerge RAILS_ENV=production
```

I found the reason from the production log.

Comment: It's described in [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide).

Comment: From what directory does this need to be run?

Comment: @Ryan From gitlabhq directory which it installed.